# Azure function with CosmosDBTrigger doesn't seem to be triggered by upserts

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm working with Azure Functions for the first time. I'm trying to write a simple function which responds to documents changed or added to a CosmosDb collection. The function I've written looks like this:

```
[FunctionName("ChangeLog")]
public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
    databaseName: "Recaptcha",
    collectionName: "Rules",
    ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection",
    LeaseCollectionName = null)]IReadOnlyList<RuleConfigCollection> documents)
{
    if (documents != null && documents.Count > 0)
    {
        ApplicationEventLogger.Write(
            Diagnostics.ApplicationEvents.RecaptchaRulesChanged,
            new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                { "SomeEnrichment", documents[0].Rules.ToList().Count.ToString() }
            });
    }
}
```

By my understanding a lease collection is necessary when multiple functions are pointed at the same CosmosDb, but in my case this isn't relevant. That's why I've set the lease collection to `null`.

I've published this to Azure from Visual Studio and can see the function is created with the following `function.json`:

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.12",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
      "connectionStringSetting": "CosmosDBConnection",
      "collectionName": "Rules",
      "databaseName": "Recaptcha",
      "leaseDatabaseName": "Recaptcha",
      "createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": false,
      "name": "documents"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/My.Namespace.Functions.App.dll",
  "entryPoint": "My.Namespace.Functions.App.ChangeLogFunction.Run"
}
```

I've also added an application setting named `CosmosDBConnection` with the value `AccountEndpoint=https://my-cosmosdb.documents.azure.com:443;AccountKey=myAccountKey;`.

I run the function then add a document to the collection, but the logs just keep saying `No new trace in the past n min(s)` and the application events I expect to see are not being written.

Have I missed something in this setup?

Comment: OK, I'm actually getting an exception thrown from one of my own dependencies now, so my function is being called. Not sure if that was since I added the lease collection as per @mikhail's comment below or not. But looks like this is now an app issue my side.

Comment: The other thing I changed was replacing `RuleConfigCollection` (my strongly-typed document model) with the generic `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document`. I'll have to look at strong typing later.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that's the root cause of you issue, but your understanding of `leaseCollection` is wrong.

`leaseCollection` is used to coordinate multiple instances (workers) of your Function App to distribute partitions between workers.

It is required even for a single Function listening to Cosmos DB change feed.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. However, even when I specify a `LeaseCollectionName` with `CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists` set to `true` I can see this collection being created, but the function is never run after adding documents to the triggering collection.