# Cosmos DB changefeed suddenly not firing Azure Function trigger

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

The Azure Function with a Cosmos DB binding will not trigger when there is an insert/update. A function with only an "input" (sql query) does process documents correctly but the one that taps the real time change feed does not.

I have tried to switch to different environments of the same data but the result stays the same. Change feed does not work - sql query input does.

How do I go about troubleshooting this methodically?

Comment: Could you provide more details or a code snippet of how is your Function with the Cosmos DB Trigger created? Have you checked the logs to see if there are any errors happening that might be blocking the Function to run? There are multiple posts covering different reasons for the Trigger not to fire: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52115599/azure-function-with-cosmosdbtrigger-doesnt-seem-to-be-triggered-by-upserts, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48342175/azure-functions-cosmosdbtrigger-not-triggering-in-visual-studio